# phpMyAdmin reports 'No Privileges' 2

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, easyphp

I have this same problem as here [phpMyAdmin reports 'No Privileges'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770348/phpmyadmin-reports-no-privileges)

However mine doesn't seem to be a cache issue, I've tested it on several browsers, uninstalled and re installed EasyPHP no luck.

I keep seeing a possible solution as

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';
```

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

However I have no idea where to insert this line. If someone can give me a step by step guide, this will be very much appreciated!

Comment: Update to the latest phpmyadmin version

Comment: I was already on the latest version. But tried the beta version, tried a different directory. No luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute that line in the query browser to grant access.

Comment: Simply entering that in the query browser, I get this: 
'Error

SQL query:

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'root'@'localhost';

MySQL said: Documentation
#1045 - Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: YES) '