# Phpmyadmin - Mysql no privileges

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I installed wamp 2.1 on windows 7. However when i open phpMyAdmin, I get the error, Mysql 'No Provileges'. I uninstalled wamp and reinstalled it a few times, but it doesn't help. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Also, when i tried creating a database from mysql console, i am getting the following error:
ERROR 1044 <42000>: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'a_db_name'

Comment: Don't connect with chrome.

See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770348/phpmyadmin-reports-no-privileges

Comment: Then have you tried connecting specifically from 127.0.0.1 instead of "localhost" ?

Comment: @Jerska yes, the problem still persists.

Comment: @Jacob if you give me the solution to my previous issues, i will definitely accept :)

Comment: What happens when you login from command line? Execute SHOW GRANTS;

Comment: I got:
Grants for @localhost
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO ''@'localhost'
1 row in set

Answer (score 12):

Thank God and to all helped.

Its simple.

1. Must! click logout icon in phpadmin page
2. In login page, type:

username:root password: (blank)

surprise. now you can happily create your database.

Answer (score 4):

Are you logging into MySQL as root? You have to explicitly grant privileges to your "regular" MySQL user account while logged in as MySQL root.

First set up a root account for your MySQL database.

In the terminal type:

```
mysqladmin -u root password 'password'
```

To log into MySQL, use this:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

**Edit:**

To set the privileges manually start the server with the skip-grant-tables option, open mysql client and manually update the mysql.user table and/or the mysql.db tables. This can be a tedious task though so if what you need is an account with all privs I would do the following.

Start the server with the `skip-grant-tables` option

Start mysql client (without a username/password)

Issue the command

```
flush privileges;
```

which forces the grant tables to be loaded.

Create a new account with the GRANT command something like this (but replacing username and password with whatever you want to use.

```
GRANT ALL on *.* to 'username'@'localhost' identified by 'password';
```

Restart the server in normal mode (without skip-grant-tables) and log in with your newly created account.

Refer [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_skip-grant-tables) MySQL docs.

Comment: I am actually unable to login as root. When i go to localhost/phpmyadmin, there are two databases there: information_schema and test. Is there anything missing?

Comment: What error are you getting now? Where are you trying to login? If you are getting 1045 error, refer this: http://www.webyog.com/faq/content/23/18/en/error-no-1045-connection-denied.html

Comment: Still the same error, "No privilege". But my guess is that mysql database is missing as well as performance_schema.

Comment: Please tell whether you are using phpmyadmin or using mysql command line now?

Comment: phpmyadmin. mysql schema is missing there as well as performance_schema.

Comment: Did you try my answer? mysqladmin -u root password 'password'
To log into MySQL, use this: mysql -u root -p

Comment: Jacob, thanks for you info above, it helped me piece together my issues in mamp.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my topic regarding this issue, which takes some of the above.

[MAMP mysql broken root user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12929722/mamp-mysql-broken-root-user/12965003#12965003)

You need to shutdown your mysql install and restart it from the command line properly like is indicated above.  In my topic I have full clear instructions on how to do so.  My instructions are for MAMP but you should be able to adapt it for your install.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution. Just find the icon right to "home" in PhpMyAdmin and click to logout. Then login using username "root" and password ""(blank). This will work accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

username ought to be root and keep the password null(keep the password field blank)

Answer (score 0):

right click on the wamp icon and goto mysql console.
Login with password if you have set any.By default the password is blank and username is 'root'
Once you are in mysql prompt execute
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
now quit the command prompt and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

in step 1 .**inter your database**very important.
in step 2 .select your database via all tables .
in step 3. backup type=replace & export.
in step 4 import database in my sql.
attention please:in import your database...
all table must view & selected in step 4.