# Moved mysql DBs between mamp installations missing tables

Tags: mysql, mamp

I've been using MAMP out of convenience but have run into major problems after mistakenly changing root permissions.  I have not been able to resolve these problems and have opted for a fresh install of MAMP and moving over the db folders, which I read was possible.  In doing so, I have a number of DBs which have tables that are MIA.

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'localhost'
response:
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*81F5E21E35407D884A6CD4A731AEBFB6AF209E1B' WITH GRANT OPTION 
GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

- I can see the all the tables in the db folder but not all are not showing up in phpmyadmin.
- I believe phpmyadmin connects as a socket "Server: Localhost via UNIX socket"
- When I login into the console as root/localhost I can see all the tables.
- Loggin into the console as root/127.0.0.1 I cannot see the DB at all.

I'm really stuck here and have pretty much lost a day of work because of this.

Update:
When I run mysql_update command I get the following response.

```
→ /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql_upgrade -p
Enter password: 
Looking for 'mysql' as: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql
Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqlcheck
Running 'mysqlcheck with default connection arguments
Running 'mysqlcheck with default connection arguments
ipbnew.ipb_admin_login_logs
Error    : Table 'ipbnew.ipb_admin_login_logs' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
ipbnew.ipb_admin_logs
Error    : Table 'ipbnew.ipb_admin_logs' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
```

Comment: Should this say 'root@localhost'?

     mysql> SELECT current_user();
     +----------------+
     | current_user() |
     +----------------+
     | @localhost     | 
     +----------------+

Comment: I've solved this and am working on a response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've posted a full explanation of the solution to my problem in a separate SO topic.

[MAMP mysql broken root user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12929722/mamp-mysql-broken-root-user/12965003#12965003)