# phpMyAdmin huge mistake - I deleted unused users and databases associated with them, how to restore

Tags: phpmyadmin, mamp

I don't care about restoring the databases or the users. The issue is really how can i create a new database using phpMyAdmin. I'm using MAMP and was creating a database and decided to delete users that are not being used anymore and in the process checked the box that said delete databases associated with these users, which deleted all of the databases.

Now i can't create a new database in phpMyAdmin because i get this huge error:

[image: Error i get when accessing phpMyAdmin]

So does this mean i ruined my MAMP and/or phpMyAdmin? Otherwise anyone have any possible solutions to remedy the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhpMyAdmin also uses the root account in your case. When this account is deleted from the tables you can't login via PhpMyAdmin anymore. Luckily there are numerous procedures for restoring the root account [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085455/restoring-deleted-root-user-and-password-for-mysql) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12929722/mamp-mysql-broken-root-user)

When the you've restored the user and entered the credentials in the PhpMyAdmin files you can login again and create databases.